# How can I draw an error bar with +sigma and -sigma?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, zedgraph

I have the following function that plots an error bar.

```
        public void AddErrorBarsTwoSigma(string curveName, List<double> xValues, List<double> yValues, List<double> yErrors, Color color)
        {
            if (xValues.Count != yValues.Count || yValues.Count != yErrors.Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("All lists must be of equal length.");
            }

            ErrorBarItem errorBar = myPane_.AddErrorBar(curveName, xValues.ToArray(), yValues.ToArray(), yErrors.ToArray(), color);
            errorBar.Bar.IsVisible = true;
            errorBar.Bar.PenWidth = DefaultLineWidth;
            errorBar.Bar.Color = color;

            // Refresh the graph to show changes
            zgc_.AxisChange();
            zgc_.Invalidate();
        }
```

[image]

The gray line is the error curve.

---

I want to modify this function so that it draws error bars one sigma up and one sigma down.

How can I do that?

---

Drive program looks like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using WeightedLinearRegressionNamespace;
using ZedGraph;

public class WeightedLinearRegression
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new ZedGraphControl
        ZedGraphControl zgc = new ZedGraphControl();
        zgc.Size = new Size(1200, 800);

        // Sample data points and their corresponding errors
        double[] xData = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        double[] yData = new double[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
        double[] yErrors = new double[] { 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7 };

        ZedGraphPlotter plotter = new ZedGraphPlotter(zgc);
        plotter.AddErrorBarsTwoSigma("bars", 
            new List<double>(xData), 
            new List<double>(yData), 
            new List<double>(yErrors), 
            Color.Red);

        plotter.AddCurve("errors", new List<double>(yErrors));

        plotter.SavePlot("", "error_bar_with_2_sigma.png");

    }
}
```